# Manage users in cancan only when admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have these models:

Company
CompanyUser
User

A CompanyUser has an attribute admin which allows him to delete other users, etc...  for that company.

In cancan I now have this but something is wrong:

```
  can [:edit, :update, :read, :destroy, :promote, :demote], CompanyUser, :company_users => { :user_id => user.id, :admin => true }
```

I want to only allow a user to edit, update, ...  CompanyUser when he is the admin for that company.  How do I need to define that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should be similar to the solution you are looking for:

```
def initialize(user)                                                          
user ||= User.new
can [:manage, :promote, :demote], CompanyUser do |cu|
  user.company_user.admin == true &&            # user is admin and
  user.comany_user.company_id == cu.company_id  # user is in the same company
end
```

If it does not match your exact case, please post the model of Company, User and CompanyUser.

Comment: Thanks! This worked after small modification to match my models.